# Drupal user points and commerce

Tags: commerce, rules, userpoints

I have 3 products: A, B and C. After the user buy the product A, I want to give the user 5 points, for B 10 points and C 20 points.

How do I do this with rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add a new rule with some name, e.g - Award Userpoint for Product A.
- In event select "Completing the checkout process".
- If you want to award userpoint only if payment has been done in full, then after going forward delete the "Completing the checkout process" & add another action "When an order is first paid in full".
- Add condition "Order contains a particular product", put the SKU of the product A. User operator & quantity as per your requirement.
- Add a action named "Grant points to a user", in data selector choose "commerce-order:owner" & set the points which you want to award.

Done...this is how I am doing.

Comment: Excellent, it worked! But there is some issue... If I buy 2 twice the product A, the system only gives me 5 points and should be 10 points. How do I do that?

Comment: @JoseDaniel - I will see what options we have in there. Please accept the answer first as it solves the question which you asked...

Comment: @JoseDaniel - Though I don't see any direct method but as per my understanding you can use rules_conditional module to put action in loops. So you will have to add a loop in action & inside that loop work on granting points to user. I guess loop will run equal to number of items..

Comment: @JoseDaniel - You can try it & let me know if it works..

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was planning do another calculation with the points, so I decided to change rules for hook_commerce_checkout_complete. I posted another question, maybe you can give some directions: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75234/drupal-commerce-get-quantity-per-sku-in-hook-commerce-checkout-complete Thanks!